# In-App purchase for two different apps

Tags: ios, xamarin, in-app-purchase

I am in the process of developing an app which needs to have a monthly subscription in-app purchase. The first version will be on the Apple platform. I have developed it using Xamarin because it need to support Android later as well. So far so good. Now I would like to start the development of the same kind of app for Apple TV, but I would like to use Xcode and Switch for that (because I prefer that). Is there a way to share the in-app purchase between the two different apps? I was first thinking of using wildcard for my bundle id, and use the same, but that does not seem to work for in-app purchase? Or am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: You can have a single app in iTunesConnect for both your iOS and tvOS builds. The builds are separate with separate binaries, so you can use different programming languages for the iOS and tvOS  releases.this means that if someone subscribes on iOS then they will get the benefit of that subscription in tvOS too

Comment: So you mean I can use the same bundle id for two different binaries?

Comment: Yes, you can use the one bundle ID for both the iOS and tvOS versions of an app; in iTunesConnect you add a new version for iOS and a new version for tvOS under the same app.

Comment: Thank you Paulw11 !